# Assembly location during the registration in the mscrm dynamics 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

During the Plugin registration, there is three option for store the assembly  1.GAC 2.Disk 3.Database

Could anyone explain that appropriate use of above location, if explain with example will more appreciable?

Answer (score 3):

You need to consider first the deployment type, if it is for CRM Online or CRM OnPremise.

For CRM Online plugin assemblies *must* be registered in Sandbox.

For CRM OnPremise plugin assemblies can be registered in Sandbox or outside the Sandbox (option None).

If the isolation mode is Sandbox the location is always Database, the advantage is that plugins stored in the database are automatically distributed across multiple CRM servers in a data center cluster.

the disadvantage is that you can't install external assemblies to the database, so if your plugin uses an external assembly you need to merge it with your plugin assembly before the registration or deploy the external assembly manually to the GAC or the the CRM bin folder.

If your register your plugin assembly outside the Sandbox (meaning you are OnPremise) you can choose to deploy it to the GAC, in this case the advantage is that you take full advantage of the GACs versioning system, preventing conflicting versions of the same assembly if multiple versions are needed.
The disadvantage is that the registration requires gacutil.exe and this can be an issue for some deployments.

If you choose to deploy to Disk, the plugin assembly will be copied to the CRM bin folder, in this case the debug will be easier (but you can debug the plugins also when they are registered in the database) but you lose also the GAC versioning advantage.